# Custom alarm app play sound from media library on interruption by local notification

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5

I want to make custom alarm app which play sound from media library in iphone. Play sound on date selected by the user on interruption by the local notification.

[I want app similar to  app on  app store](http://itunes.apple.com/pl/app/alarm-clock%2a/id514529508?mt=8&ls=1)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Consider reading the iOS App Programming Guide -> App States and Multitasking:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html

Read the following part: *"Implementing Long-Running Background Tasks"* and **Playing Background Audio**

You can't do that with normal local notifications, as they have a limit of 30 seconds and you cannot let the user choose the file. You have to import it in your app bundle and include it in your code!!!

I really think there is no other way then abusing the background audio playback system to keep your app running in the background, then present a local notification with no sound and play the sound out of a call in your background app with a system library (core audio etc...)

Comment: Thanks for reply, but i have already read it.but i do not know how use it. did you see alarm app or not? if you saw it, you can understand what i want.

Comment: i really understand that what you want! And I know how to do it and I explained it to you. I cannot write the whole code. I think the App is playing a silent sound until the reminder will start (hack to stay background executed). Then a local push is sent and then the self choosen track is played.